# Merging/Copying Specific files to master from Branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I run following command to find file names that were changes in branch but NOT in master:

```
git diff --name-status master..branchName
```

It gives a list of file names with full path.

Now I have cloned `master` on local machine and want to copy, those changed files in master. I said `copy` as I don't want to merge and run into conflicts.

Is there a way to get some kind of patch which have files in relevant  folders? instead of manually copying them?

Comment: Do you want a *patch* or a verbatim copy of some files in the branch in order to fully overwrite those files in the master branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just redirect output of the `git diff` command to a file.

```
$ git diff master..branchName -- the/relevant/path1 the/relevant/path2 ... > my.patch
```

Then use `git apply my.patch` to apply the changes all at once.

Another option is to checkout the files/directories that you want:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git chechout branchName -- the/relevant/path1 the/relevant/path2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to have the working directory and index of your branch and your repository pointing to master commit.

The way to do that is with [git-reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset/):

```
git checkout yourBranch
git branch tempBranch   // It is allways safer create a temporal branch when you play with git-reset
git reset --soft master // This moves to master commit but does not touch your working directory and index area.
```